# replacing existing DOM-Element with replaceChild()

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i am creating a simple weather app with js and i'm running into a problem. i added an eventlistener that runs the function to fetch the data from the weather api and creates 2 divs and displays the fetched information.

the problem:
the divs are created without problem, but the issue appears when the next click-event follows, the existing div in the DOM should be replaced by the new created one.
i'm trying different variations with the replaceChild() method but can't make it work.

Any held would be much appreciated.

here's the code:

```
let getWeatherBtn = document.querySelector("#btn");

getWeatherBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log("this is the statechange function")

    stateChange();
});
function stateChange() {

    let dropdownElmt = document.getElementById("dropdownMenu");
    let dropdownValue = dropdownElmt.value;
    let URL = "";
    let regionImage = "";

    if (dropdownValue === 'schluchsee') {
        URL = 'https://api.climacell.co/v3/weather/realtime?lat=47.798916919872866&lon=8.183037307776177&unit_system=si&fields=temp%2Cprecipitation_type&apikey=me2Qm6ZYZ7V8CUhZ5FopsDhQdsqmeV6a'
        regionImage = "../img/schluchsee-blick.jpg"
    }

    if (dropdownValue === 'schauinsland') {
        URL = 'https://api.climacell.co/v3/weather/realtime?lat=47.91368287150694&lon=7.898325385069348&unit_system=si&fields=temp%2Cprecipitation_type&apikey=me2Qm6ZYZ7V8CUhZ5FopsDhQdsqmeV6a'
        regionImage = "../img/schauinsland.jpg"
    }

    if (dropdownValue === 'todtmoos') {
        URL = 'https://api.climacell.co/v3/weather/realtime?lat=47.7416329953509&lon=8.004721615344211&unit_system=si&fields=temp%2Cprecipitation_type&apikey=me2Qm6ZYZ7V8CUhZ5FopsDhQdsqmeV6a'
        regionImage = "../img/todtmoos.jpg"
    }

    if (dropdownValue === 'sustenpass') {
        URL = 'https://api.climacell.co/v3/weather/realtime?lat=46.733239716311395&lon=8.432407803492424&unit_system=si&fields=temp%2Cprecipitation_type&apikey=me2Qm6ZYZ7V8CUhZ5FopsDhQdsqmeV6a'
        regionImage = "../img/sustenpass.jpg";
    }




    let xhrWeather = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhrWeather.open("GET", URL, true);
    xhrWeather.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    xhrWeather.setRequestHeader('apikey', 'MyToken**********');

    xhrWeather.onreadystatechange = function () {

        



        if (xhrWeather.readyState === 4 && xhrWeather.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhrWeather.responseText)
            //get value from dropdown menu

          
            let temps = Object.values(JSON.parse(xhrWeather.responseText));
            let weatherTextNode = document.createElement("div");
            let regionPictureNode = document.createElement("div");
            let weatherParagraph = document.createElement("p");
            let tempParagraph = document.createElement("p");
            

            let existingElementCheck = !!document.querySelector(".bigContainer");
            
            if (existingElementCheck) {
                
                let bigContainer = document.querySelector(".bigContainer");
                let container = document.querySelector(".container")
                console.log(container)
                


                console.log(existingElementCheck)
                container = document.createElement("div")
                console.log(container)
                let newContainer = document.createElement("div")
                console.log(newContainer)
                newContainer.setAttribute("class", "newContainer")
                newContainer = newContainer.appendChild(weatherTextNode)
                newContainer = newContainer.appendChild(regionPictureNode)


                
                bigContainer.replaceChild(newContainer, container)



            }


           

            


            



           

            weatherTextNode.setAttribute("class", "col-md-6");
            weatherTextNode.setAttribute("id", "weatherTextDiv")
            regionPictureNode.setAttribute("class", "col-md-6");
            weatherParagraph.setAttribute("id", "weatherP");
            tempParagraph.setAttribute("id", "tempP");

            let imagenode = document.createElement("img");
            imagenode.setAttribute('width', '350px');
            imagenode.setAttribute('height', '200px');
            imagenode.src = regionImage;
            let tempTextnode = document.createTextNode("The current temperature is: " + temps[2]['value'] + "  Celsius");
            let precipitationTextnode = document.createTextNode("Is there currently any rain? " + temps[3]['value']);
            tempParagraph.appendChild(tempTextnode);
            weatherTextNode.appendChild(tempParagraph);


            weatherParagraph.appendChild(precipitationTextnode)
            weatherTextNode.appendChild(weatherParagraph);

            regionPictureNode.appendChild(imagenode);


            document.querySelector('.bigContainer').appendChild(weatherTextNode)
            document.querySelector('.bigContainer').appendChild(regionPictureNode)



           












        }
        else {
            console.log("bad stuff")
        }
    };
    xhrWeather.send()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem where you declare the `container` variable and assign it the value of `document.querySelector(".container")`. However three lines later you assign it a new element (`document.createElement("div")`) and it does not exists in the dom that means you can not really replace it.

Part of the code in question:

```
if (existingElementCheck) {
            
            let bigContainer = document.querySelector(".bigContainer");
            // declaration
            let container = document.querySelector(".container")
            console.log(container)
            


            console.log(existingElementCheck)
            // ?new assignment?
            container = document.createElement("div")
            console.log(container)
            let newContainer = document.createElement("div")
            console.log(newContainer)
            newContainer.setAttribute("class", "newContainer")
            newContainer = newContainer.appendChild(weatherTextNode)
            newContainer = newContainer.appendChild(regionPictureNode)


            
            bigContainer.replaceChild(newContainer, container)



        }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. i put this line in, because without that line, i got the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'.

so i thought that the replaceChild method only accepts newly created nodes. That's why i tried to create one and assign it to the container variable.

i don't understand why the replaceChild won't accepts my container node.

Comment: That is because `document.querySelector(...)` returns an element instead of node, that comes really handy when you want to modify it but here the function requires a node as the second argument. You can try something like `bigContainer.childNodes[0]` which returns a node.